# WP7 Complex Layout 

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, layout

I want to make a complex layout, and would like advice on the best way to go about this.

Here is the behaviour I'm looking for: Layout of some text blocks and some images, such that a tap anywhere on the layout will go to another related page to that item. I want a long list of this item in a scroll viewer.

First, I tried to make a grid, add the items in it, then add this grid in the outer grid, the main one for pressing, I made an event handler for mouse click, but a problem appeared; that when I try to scroll "on the item to view the all list" the event handler fired!, I tried the `mouseButton` up and down, and the same happen

Second, I'm not sure if it's an efficient way to make it.
I want a good way to design this complex layout, and of course it will be a programmatic way, and a way to recognize the item I press on.

Comment: "sorry for long question" that's OK but the lack of punctuation and paragraphs is unforgivable.

Comment: I've modded this back up one because he never said he wanted to created a new control. Rather than mod the question down, it would have been more appropriate to explain that the best way to create such a layout would be to use a listbox with a DataTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to create your own `ListBox` control. Using this will give you the scrolling functionality for free, and you can use the `ListBox`'s `SelectionChanged` event to determine when an item has been clicked.

The best way to design the layout will depend on how complex it actually is. If it merely contains an image and some text, you should have no problem hand-coding that in XAML. If there's a lot more to it than that, I'd recommend looking into Microsoft's Blend tool. Whichever route you choose to produce the XAML, you will place the code in the `ListBox`'s `ItemTemplate`, which determines how each item in the `ListBox` is displayed.

A good walkthrough of something similar to what you're doing can be found at http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2010/10/27/windows-phone-list-box-with-images.aspx